# How can I include PHP code from another file in hook_nodeapi()?

Tags: nodes, 6

I am embedding HTML and loading JavaScript code in a node using `hook_nodeapi()`.

```php
function first_order_decay_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'alter') {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'first_order_decay');
    $path .= '/';
    $code = file_get_contents($path . 'templates/first_order_decay-static.tpl.php', false);
    $code = preg_replace("/[\r\n]*/","",$code);
    $code = preg_replace("/<!--EMBEDREMOVE-->.+<!--EMBEDREMOVE-->/","",$code);
    $pos = strpos($node->body, '[FLOT](kinetics1)');

    if ($pos !== false) {
      $node->body = substr_replace($node->body, $code, $pos, strlen('[FLOT](kinetics1)'));
    }
  }
}
```

How can I parse PHP into HTML from the `$code` variable? It seems that because the page is already in the rendering process, Drupal ignores the PHP code. Is there another phase of `hook_nodeapi()` I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function used by Drupal to render a template is [`theme_render_template()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_render_template/6), used by [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/6).

```
  extract($variables, EXTR_SKIP); // Extract the variables to a local namespace
  ob_start(); // Start output buffering
  include "./$template_file"; // Include the template file
  $contents = ob_get_contents(); // Get the contents of the buffer
  ob_end_clean(); // End buffering and discard
  return $contents; // Return the contents
```

You can adapt that code to your need.

As for using the code you are using, I am not sure I would do the same. The main problem with your code is handling directly the template files; Drupal 8 changes how the template files are rendered, and your code would need to be changed.
Apart this, there is a better way to achieve what you are trying to achieve, using a theme function that uses a template file. See [`node_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_theme/6) and what that function returns for the node theme function. Drupal doesn't uses template files directly, when rendering a node, but it calls the theme hook with `theme('node')`.

The pro of using a theme hook is that the output of your module could be alter from another module, if that would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As i get you, you need to implement hook_theme and use it, instead parsing php code.

Please, see anwser here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985689/how-to-implement-hook-theme-in-drupal-7